# Rust: "multiple applicable items in scope" error for ndarray dot product on slice

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I think I ended up figuring out a solution while asking this but figured I'd leave the question up anyway...

I'm working with n-dimensional matrices using the `ndarray` crate and I need to take dot-products of multiple non-contiguous slices. However, I run into an issue as the compiler can't seem to figure out if my slices are 1D or 2D when it comes to taking a dot product and I'm not sure how to specify this information.

Here is a simplified example:

```
use ndarray::prelude::*;

fn main() {

    let a = array![[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];
    println!("{:?}", &a);

    let b = array![[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];
    println!("{:?}", &b);

    let a_slice = a.slice(s![0, ..]);
    let b_slice = b.slice(s![0, ..]);

    println!("{:?}", &a_slice.dot(&b_slice));

}
```

The error message is a bit confusing, and I don't know how to make the dot product use the right candidate given the abstracted structs involved:

```
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
  --> src/main.rs:14:31
   |
14 |     println!("{:?}", &a_slice.dot(&b_slice));
   |                               ^^^ multiple `dot` found
   |
   = note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `ndarray::ArrayBase<_, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
   = note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl for the type `ndarray::ArrayBase<_, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
```

How do I provide the necessary information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the error message referring to `ArrayBase`, the important piece of information here is actually the dimensions of the slice. So providing explicit dimensions using `ArrayView` does the trick:

```
use ndarray::prelude::*;

fn main() {

    let a = array![[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];
    println!("{:?}", &a);

    let b = array![[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];
    println!("{:?}", &b);

    let a_slice: ArrayView<_, Ix1> = a.slice(s![0, ..]);
    let b_slice: ArrayView<_, Ix1> = b.slice(s![0, ..]);

    println!("{:?}", &a_slice.dot(&b_slice));

}
```